# How to add a range next to a list of numbers

Tags: excel

I am trying to a a range column next to a list of numbers using a formula.  For example I have a column of 1 through 10 and I am trying to get a column next to the numbers if they fall in the range ( "1 to 4" and "5 to 10")  How can I do this using a formula?

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Following textually your logic, that would be (say, in cell B2) something like `=IF(AND(1<=A2,A2<=4),1,IF(AND(5<=A2,A2<=10),2,"Undefined"))`. But this question is probably better suited for some other SE site.

Answer (score 0):

It think this formula will do what you are asking.

```
=IF(AND(A1>=1,A1<=4),"1 to 4",IF(AND(A1>=5,A1<=10),"5 to 10","-")
```

If the number is outside of the 1-10 range it will return -